# No se puede desesctructurar la propiedad 'data' porque es indefinida

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

**Necesito mostrar en una tabla los datos traidos desde una api hecha en spring boot, la cuestion es que cuando envio el get en postman me devuelve todo perfectamente
Adjunto la imagen:**
[image: Postman]

**En react hago lo siguiente: (Adjunto el codigo)**

[image: Codigo react]
[image: Codigo react 2]

**En la consola me devuelve los datos perfectamente pero no logro mostrarlos en las tablas, no se que estoy haciendo mal**

[image: Consola]

**Este es mi codigo de Axios donde llamo a la Api**

[image: Services]

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta "Java"?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, el código debe ir como texto, [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Saludos

Comment: El log de que es, del estado o de la data que obtenes en el get?
Y podrías adjuntar una captura de la parte donde renderizas esa data, la parte de la tabla

Comment: @FrancoMendo el log viene del metodo getAll() en el service, o sea los datos los trae pero no los puedo mostrar en la tabla. (edité las imagenes para que veas el log en el service y lo que me aparece en la consola de la web)

Comment: Posiblemente tengas que hacer referencia al primer elemento del array y por eso no te permite destructurar el objeto ya que data es un array, intenta seteando el estado con data[0]
o tambien podes intentar logear el estado que usas para renderizar en pantalla, para ver si se está seteando bien o que dato le llega

Comment: Podrías agregar la screenshot del render? o cómo lo estarías renderizando?